# How to obtain list of permissions given to my app?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions

I want to retrieve all the list of permissions that were granted to my app by the user. For example, if my app asks for `CAMERA`, `LOCATION` and `INTERNET` permissions and only `CAMERA` and `INTERNET` permissions were granted by the user. How do I get a list that looks like

`grantedPermissions=[CAMERA, INTERNET]`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this simple method which will return true if permission is Granted by the user otherwise false :

```
 private boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String permissionName) {
    return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permissionName) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}
```

call of method be like `hasPermissions(context,Manifest.permission.CAMERA);`